# How to retrieve Timestamp value from SQL Server using DataReader

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008

How to retrieve Timestamp value(eg:0x000000048E18B9D8 ) from SQL Server using `DataReader`? I'm getting an `IndexOutOfRangeException` when doing like this

```
DateTime date = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("Timestamp"));
```

Can anyone help on this?

Also I want to know how to pass timestamp parameter to stored procedure using .Net code

Comment: What is the column's name in your table? Obviously, it's *not* called `timestamp`...... also: the `TIMESTAMP` datatype in SQL Server has **nothing** to do with actual date and time - I hope you are aware of this!

Comment: A timestamp is not a date or time or datetime in SQL Server. Why are you trying to get it in a datetime variable?

Comment: you can create an instance of `SqlParameter` and add it to the parameter list of your `SqlCommand` object, which will eventually the procedure.

Comment: I have the same question. How do I retrieve the timestamp in SQL as string in C#.

Answer (score 1):

`IndexOutOfRangeException` thrown on `reader.Getordinal()` suggests that a column called `Timestamp` doesn't exist. Check your column names again, and replace with the actual value. By default, it will be called `timestamp`, but only if you haven't specified a column name.

You could also try `string ts = reader["timestamp"].toString()`, and make sure it returns something.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=sql.90).aspx), a `TIMESTAMP` data type is *"8 bytes...[and]... just an incrementing number and does not preserve a date or a time. To record a date or time, use a datetime data type."*

Therefore, `reader.GetInt64()` is probably close, if you really need this value, but `byte[] myTimestamp = reader["timestamp"]` is probably better.

As far as passing it back to your stored procedure, you can create a new parameter with `SqlDbType.Timestamp`. The value will be a byte array, or, if you have it stored as a string, you could try something like:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@TimeStampParam", SqlDbType.Timestamp).Value = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myTimestampStr);`
```

(NB: I haven't tested this, but it should be close enough).

Note that `TIMESTAMP` is deprecated, and `ROWVERSION` is not the preferred syntax.

Comment: how can i retrieve timestamp data.its not matter whether it is datetime.currently it is having value like  0x000000048E18B9D8

Comment: what kind of `TimeStamp` is this?

Comment: @vmb: There are a few ways, perhaps you could add your table schema to your question so we can get a clearer picture. In the meantime, I've added more detail to my answer.

Comment: @Michael McMullin..thanks..u answered my first question.Second question:How can i pass this to an SP which is having input parameter with data type "timestamp" through commandParameter

Comment: @vmb: I've added some information about timestamp parameters above.